# Why is my Future Value app instantly returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

Here is a simple JavaScript-HTML Future Value app that takes in the investment amount, interest rate, and how many years the investment will last and is supposed to return the final outcome. But for some reason, it returns a NaN right away when the page finishes loading. Google Chrome dev tools didn't show any errors. Can someone please help?

Did I miss a keyword or is the syntax just wrong?

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
var calculateFV = function(investment, rate, years) {
  var futureValue = investment;
  for (var i = 0; i < years; i++) {
    futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * rate / 100);
  }
  futureValue = parseFloat(futureValue);
  futureValue = futureValue.toFixed(2);
  return futureValue;
};
var processEntries = function() {
  var investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);
  var rate = parseFloat($("rate").value);
  var years = parseFloat($("years").value);

  return $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, rate, years);
};
window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries();
  $("investment").focus();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="future_value.css">
    <script src="future_value.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>
        
        <label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="investment"><br>
        
        <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" id="rate">%<br>
        
        <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
        <input type="text" id="years"><br>
        
        <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>
        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>      
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("calculate").onclick = processEntries();` Remove the parentheses: `$("calculate").onclick = processEntries;`

Comment: `$("calculate").onclick = processEntries()` assigns to the onclick whatever **executing** `processEntries()` returns. You only need the parentheses when you assign the clickhandler in an HTML `onclick` **attribute**.